# HaspDotNetDllBroken error

Tags: asp.net, dll, hasp

I am using Safenet Sentinel key, I have created a webservice for login but when i run it the first time it throws an error HASPDotNetDllBroken but runs fine if i run it the second time or consecutively after that.
I am using the following dlls:

- apidsp_windows.dll
- hasp_net_windows.dll

and my webservice is:

```
[WebMethod]
public string Log()
{
    HaspFeature feature = HaspFeature.Default;

    string vendorCode="Az........";

      Hasp hasp = new Hasp(feature);

    HaspStatus status = hasp.Login(vendorCode);

    if (HaspStatus.StatusOk != status)
    {
        return("Login Failed with status "+status.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        return ("Login Successful with status "+status.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the dll's you mention it seems your webservice is 32-bit. In that case you have to put the apidsp_windows.dll and the hasp_windows_.dll in the System32 directory on 32-bit machines and in the SysWOW64 directory on 64-bit machines.  is your numeric vendorid, or demo if you're running in evaluation mode.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Yes absolutely, thats what I did and resolved the issue, thanks for the help anyway.